# Grid View rotation handling

Tags: android, gridview

I have slight problem. I have `gridView` in main activity, and on device rotation the list will always start from the top. I fonud several solutions but non of them work for gridView. How can I maintain same gridView position on device rotation using `onSavedInstanceState`?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to understand the facts because of which this is happening. This is happening because whenever your device orientation changes your onDestroy() and onCreate() lifecycle methods are called. To survive your activity state using onSaveInstanceState, you need to save your grid view scroll position when onDestroy() is called and then retrieve it in your onCreate() method. You can do this using Bundle. The code will look something like this, onSaveInstanceState() will be called by android os before your activity get destroyed \n

```
     @Override
     onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);          
        bundle.putInt("SCROLL_VIEW_POSITION",scroll_position);
    }

   //And in your on Create
   onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
       int scrollPosition = saveInstanceState.get("SCROLL_VIEW_POSITION",default_value);
   }
```

Once you get your same scrollPosition before oreientation change you can use it to set scroll position of your grid view.

Comment: if I put it in on create app is crashing on starting ... if I don't then app is crashing on rotation and it says ''cannot envoke destroy method'' :/

Comment: it will be good, if you can share your code, so that i can see whats going wrong :)

Comment: https://github.com/ivanbumbak/PopularMovies2 ... but you need to have API key for displaying the list ... :/

Comment: check the answer now I made few mistakes in a hurry, it should work now

Comment: still doesn't work ... also I have one more state in onSavedInstance so this.onSavedInstace(bundle) won't work